# Drag 'n' drop won't work on my sublime text 2 installation

Tags: windows, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I installed sublime text 2 on my windows system and haven't been able to drag and drop directories/folder from windows onto the app. The documentation says it has this feature.

Comment: Running as administrator seems to do it - bit of a pain on windows 8 considering you run into problems creating files etc without it :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all. I only recently noticed it is because I always ran the app as an administrator. If you run apps as an administrator, you may loose such features. I noticed that with notepad too.

You can learn from that.

*NB: Could not post as an answer when I first asked the question, so I had to edit my answer. Posting now as an answer since i have enough reputation to do so.*

Answer (score 0):

Did you try "dropping" on the `FOLDERS` bar on the left? It works without a problem and I'm running `2.0.1 build 2217`

Answer (score -1):

If you drag a folder into Sublime Text you'll see the folder name appear in the title bar. If your sidebar isn't opened, you can open it by going to View > Side Bar > Show Side Bar.